# iOS 11 UIRefreshControl with NavigationBar LargeTitle and SearchController disappearing

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have a navigationBar with largeTitle and searchcontroller and my tableView has a refreshcontrol.

When I pull to refresh the activityIndicator of refreshcontrol disappear but de refresh process continues, even when the process finish and I call .endRefreshing() of UIRefreshControll the navigationBar doesn't back to the normal size.

[image]

Someone with the same problem?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. After refreshing is complete, the underlying table view makes a jump back to its original position but the navigation bar stays in the refresh state. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @xxtesaxx My answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47659869/2145198

Answer (score 28):

I searched a solution for this for weeks already and today, I finally made it work. The solution is so simple, I can't believe I haven't found that earlier.

I was using a normal UIViewController with a UITableView. My layout constraints were setup so that the UITableView was pinned with 0 to the bottom and top layout guides like so:

[image]

Once I changed that and pinned the UITableView to the Superview with 0 to all edges, it magically started to work:

[image]

I didn't even have to setup anything else. I hope so much that this does the fix for you as well because its just so annoying...

---

If the above doesn't work, than you need in addition to it, set

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

or check the "Extend Edges / Under Opque Bar" in the Storyboard

Comment: This saved me such a headache! Do you know why this was the case?

Comment: Didn't worked for me unfortunately... (doing it via view code instead of storyboard)

Comment: Do you setup constraints via code? Make sure to not pin your scroll view tot he layout guides or safe area but the superview top and bottom.

Comment: @BrunoRocha my solution may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47659869/2145198

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 13):

Try

`self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;`

If you have opaque navigation bars that is. It fixed the issue for me.

Comment: It fixed for me ! Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm! The tableview jumped back up, but the navigation bar stayed big. Oh and the indicator was invisible... all fixed thanks to you!

Comment: This worked ONLY, when i done also what is in xxtesaxx answer

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this code snippet:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true;
```

Comment: Context? Where and when are you using this?