# iOS 11 search bar animation bug

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a search controller attached to a navigation item with a customized search bar styling (colors). Here is the code:

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    let bar = searchController.searchBar
    bar.placeholder = "Search songs"
    bar.backgroundImage = .transparentPixel // transparent UIImage of size 1x1
    bar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.02, green: 0.04, blue: 0.06, alpha: 1)
    bar.tintColor = .white
    bar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.02, green: 0.04, blue: 0.06, alpha: 1)
    bar.isTranslucent = false
    bar.barStyle = .default
    bar.showsCancelButton = true

    definesPresentationContext = true
```

and then I add it to the controller:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        controller.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        controller.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

When I navigate to that controller for a small amount of time during the animation the search bar displays white color instead of the ones I set up. Not sure if those are default styling or just one white background color. Here is the video:

[image]

During debugging the view hierarchy I found a white background, not sure if it has anything to do with the problem:

[image]
[image]

---

**UPDATE:** The official Apple sample code for searching (can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)) has similar problem. In addition it displays black area below search bar while animating a push of a new controller. I have changed the background color of the window to red and saw red color instead:

[image]

In my case I have no window or views with white background. Would be interesting to understand if anyone had this problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed the same bug, by deleting background image setting

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

I found this solution below.

[iOS 11 UIRefreshControl with NavigationBar LargeTitle and SearchController disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793716/ios-11-uirefreshcontrol-with-navigationbar-largetitle-and-searchcontroller-disap)

Comment: Explain more your answer