# Swift: "Poppy" LargeTitles After Refresh

Tags: swift

I have this situation where my LargeTitles became "popped" after a refresh was done. I have implemented accordingly like so in this linked [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793716/ios-11-uirefreshcontrol-with-navigationbar-largetitle-and-searchcontroller-disap) but programmatically, but received this issue like so:

[image]

My code as such:

```
//Declarations:
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.backgroundColor = .customGroupedTableViewBackgroundColor
    tv.contentInset.top = -36
    return tv
}()

lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let rc = UIRefreshControl(frame: .zero)
    rc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshControlDidRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    return rc
}()

//At viewDidLoad()
view.addSubview(tableView)

navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.title = "Carparks"

tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

Any advice how do I remove that snappy behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve it by adding `tv.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` to my tableView declaration:

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.backgroundColor = .customGroupedTableViewBackgroundColor
    tv.contentInset.top = -35
    tv.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    return tv
}()
```